# SQL query syntax with ORDER BY not working

Tags: c#, sql

I am new to C# but I know SQL quite well. I have a query that works fine in SQL editor, but I can't integrate it in my code. It throws wrong SQL syntax Exception. The original SQL query which works fine is :

> select distinct description from Table_A where id = '001' order by description;

The C# string would be like:

```
_cmd.CommandText = "select distinct description from Table_A where Plant_ID =" + _selectedPlantID + "order by description";
```

The above query works in C# program when I remove the `+ "order by description` part. Here `_selectedPlantID` is the only variable that gets value in the program. I am quite sure that there should be some quotes problem, but to me everything looks fine, so was wondering if there is any other specific way to write this in C#?

Comment: You should not create your queries by concatting strings together; you're opening yourself up to SQL injection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a space between `"` and `'order by`, this would work :

```
 _cmd.CommandText = "select distinct description from Table_A where Plant_ID ='" + _selectedPlantID + "' order by description";
```

But since it is open to SQL Injection (comprehensive example [here](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html)), consider using [parametized queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead :

```
_cmd.CommandText = "select distinct description from Table_A where Plant_ID = ? order by description";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@plant", _selectedPlantID );
```

Comment: @user3218207 I added the documentation and a interesting SQL Injection article as well.

Comment: @user3218207 Please tell me the error you get, so I can fix it

Comment: It is like :ERROR [42000] [SAP AG][LIBODBCHDB32 DLL][HDBODBC32] Syntax error or access violation;257 sql syntax error: incorrect syntax near "@": line 1 col 104 (at pos 104)
ERROR [S1000] [SAP AG][LIBODBCHDB32 DLL][HDBODBC32] General error;-10210 Invalid command state (No prepared SQL command)

Comment: @user3218207 I assumed you where using `SqlCommand`, but I guess you use `OdbcCommand`. Change "@plant" in query by "?" as I did and it will be ok.

Comment: Could you please tell me what if I have 2 variables like : select * from table_A where x ='2' and y = '3' order by y;

Comment: @user3218207 With `OdbcCommand`, the only important thing is the order in which you add the parameters. So just add them at the right order to get them on the right place on the query ! (in your example, use two `?` and add `2` first, then `3`)

Comment: So you mean command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@plant", _selectedPlantID ); is no more needed ? Then where to add the values 2 and 3 , can u be clearer or should i browse more ...  :/

Comment: Take a look at my PasteBin here : http://pastebin.com/8vyritmG , it is an example with 2 parameters, but of course you can add as much as you want. Note that the name of the parameters don't do anything. They are just (in the case of `OdbcCommand`) here for readability.

Comment: but that didnt work for my scenario, no idea why, the string.format works though... anyway, thank u so much

Comment: @user3218207 Give me your error. Furthermore, can you confirm you are using an `OdbcCommand` object ?

Answer (score 14):

This is what your SQL looks like in C# after replacing `1` as the `_selectedPlantID`:

```
select distinct description from Table_A where id =1order by description
```

You see the problem?

However, instead of adding a space to "fix" the problem, please use [parameterized queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead. This issue you have just encountered is just *one* of the troubles of "concatenating strings and parameters"; the most dangerous, however, is [*SQL injection*](http://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer, and it worked, would consider the parameterised queries for sure :)

Answer (score 3):

You need a space before the ORDER BY clause in the string, like this:

```
_cmd.CommandText = "select distinct description from Table_A where Plant_ID =" + _selectedPlantID + " order by description";
```

Comment: You didn't explain ANYTHING! I gave a perfect acceptable answer!

Comment: The answer is technically correct, but it's just some duct tape over the true problem

Comment: That is ANOTHER problem, not the current one. I am not forced to add the danger of SQL injection when solving the initial problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using string.Format is often a nice way to concatenate strings too, especially if you have lots of strings to combine:

```
_cmd.CommandText = string.Format("select distinct description from Table_A where Plant_ID ='{0}' order by description", _selectedPlantID);
```

Comment: Hi, here if I have an approach like make the query based on scenario, that is order it when needed, add condn when needed etc, how can i format the query i.e , my 3 variable qry = "select description frm tableA", qryorder = "order by decription" , qryAppend = "where id= _selectedPlantID". In this case, can i use string format somehow ? any suggestion ?

Comment: You could leave have an ordinal position for each area that you might substitute a string in for and either leave it blank or write a condition. Does that make sense?

Comment: mm.. actually i didnt get u :), btw i may need qry variable alone, only in certain cases i need to use qryOrder and qryappend. So how do i use ordinal position..i dont think its possible, is it ?

Comment: Use `{0}` for your `WHERE` clause line, `{1}` for your `ORDER BY` line. Then if you need to use them populate the respective variables with strings, otherwise simply set them to `string.Empty`.